# setContentType and !DOCTYPE tag

Tags: java, html

I am doing some java code as:

> PrintWriter writer = null;
>                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

```
         try {
             writer = response.getWriter();
         }
         catch (IOException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         if (userValue != null){
             userValue = getRandInt(userValue);
             writer.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
         }
```

Should I write `writer.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");`

if I use `response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");`?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using html 5?

Comment: Yes. Browsers use DOCTYPE definition in order to scheme how to display a page (in standard or compatible modes)

Comment: I don't know. It is university task. How can I define it?

Comment: The doctype above is that one of html5.

Comment: Mark, thanks. But I use "setContentType". There I set "text/html"

Comment: It depends on what you trying to achive? Will it be passed into browser or saved as a html file, or it just will processed in your program. In first case you should do as I said. In second it doesn't matter.

Comment: If it's a school task do it as I said. It won't hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set both.

The ContentType header is a nice hint how to display the data here utf-8 encoded HTML. The doctype helps the browser to know that here comes a html 5 document. This is important for the browser so it knows that this is no old webpage which requires the quirks mode where the CSS implementation has to handle with and padding diffrent ([error box model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug)).